# Segmenting on users who have performed a behaviour not behaving as expected

Tags: session, google-analytics, persistence, segments

I want to look at the effect of having performed a specific action sequence *at any (tracked) time in the past* on user retention and engagement.

The action sequence is that of performing an optional New User Flow.
This is signalled to Google Analytics via sending it appropriate events.   That works fine.   The events show up in reports as expected.

My problem is what happens to results when I used these events to create segments.   I have tried two different ways of creating a segment based on this in Advanced Segmentations, via Conditions (defining the segment via the end event, filtered over users not sessions), and via Sequences (defining start and end events, again filtered over users not sessions).

What I get when I look at various retention/loyalty reports, using either of these segments, is ever so very clearly a result which is doing this segmentation within session, not across uses sessions.   So for NUF completers , I am seeing all my loyalty/recency on Session 1, in which people are most likely to do the NUF, if they ever do it at all.   This is not what I want.   (Mind you it is something that could be really useful in other context, with another event!  But not for the new user flow.)

What are my options for getting what I want?   I see two possible ways forward:

1. Using custom dimensions,  assigning a custom dimension value in the code when the New User Flow is completed.   However I do not know if this will solve the cross-session persistence problem.

   2. Injecting a UserID, which we do not currently do, and (somehow!) using the reports available when you inject a UserID to do this.

Are either of these paths plausible?  Is there a better way forward?    Is it silly to even try to do this in Google Analytics?  I'm way more familiar with App Tracking solutions (e.g. Flurry, Mixpanel, DeltaDNA) which do this as a matter of course,  than with Google Analytics, and the fact this is at the very least awkward in Google Analytics is coming a bit of a surprise.

thanks,

Heather

Comment: The documentation really does suggest that what I am doing is possible:   https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951 Talking about hit, session vs user scope.   User: Behaviour across all the sessions within the date range that you’re using, up to 90 days; for example, all the goals that users completed or all the revenue that they generated (across all the sessions) during the date range.

Comment: Please could the person who voted to close this question elaborate on why they believe this question is badly phrased and/or inappropriate?